# Which construction is correct? Make the choice of wisdom or make the choice with wisdom ?

Tags: word-stress

which construction is grammatically correct? Make the choice of wisdom or  make the choice with wisdom?

Comment: _Choose wisely_ is a concise and understandable way to express this thought.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct but have different meaning:

```
Make the choice of wisdom:
```

This describes someone who has decided to follow a path (or life) of wisdom.

```
Make the choice with wisdom:
```

This describes someone who is using wisdom to help them when making a specific choice.